How to Test Airflow DAG Locally While My Airflow Environment is Running on a Remote Docker?
I currently have my Airflow environment running in a Docker container on a remote server, but I would like to test my DAGs locally before pushing them to the remote environment.
I'm not sure what the best way is to set up a local testing environment for this. Should I mirror the remote setup locally in Docker, or is there a simpler way to test DAGs without needing to replicate the entire environment?
Here’s some context:

Airflow is already set up on a remote server (inside Docker).
I want to test and debug DAGs on my local machine before deploying them.
Any advice or best practices for setting this up would be much appreciated!
I use VS Code for development


you can install airflow on your computer/laptop using docker.
